# Exernal addresses not resolving

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi

I recently changed ISPs. I got a new router. After a lot of messing about I have the router running almost the way I want it. However, since then my Raspberry Pi can't resolve external addresses. So, doing stuff like `ping www.google.com` the name doesn't resolve. I get the following message:

```
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The interfaces in `/etc/network` has this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.42
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

resolv.conf contains this:

```
domain Home
search Home
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

When I do `dig google.com @192.168.0.1` I get

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Raspbian <<>> google.com @192.168.0.1 
;; global options: +cmd 
;; Got answer: 
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42497 
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION: 
;google.com. IN A 

;; ANSWER SECTION: 
google.com. 289 IN A 216.58.198.110

;; Query time: 17 msec 
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1) 
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 20 10:36:14 GMT 2018 
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 44
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/482121/edit) your question and post the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: is the py connected via physical ether-net cable to the router?

Comment: It uses ethernet, not wifi.

Comment: Edited to show resolv.conf. I have to say I hadn't thought of that but the IP address in there for the nameserver is the IP address of the router. Personally I would have thought the router acts as a DNS for the network wouldn't it?

Comment: What do you get if you do `dig google.com @192.168.0.1` and `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Dig output:

`; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Raspbian <<>> google.com @192.168.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42497
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             289     IN      A       216.58.198.110

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 20 10:36:14 GMT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have set the Py's IP address as a static address. This is probably not what you want.

Most modern networks use DHCP. There will be a DHCP server built into the router/ethernet-switch/modem combo that your ISP provided.

You need to set the mode of the interface to auto.

On my py the file `/etc/network/interfaces` contains only

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

and `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` is empty directory.

Comment: Yes, I do want a static IP. That is why it is configured that way. The static IP range on the router is between 2 and 127. Anything from 128 upwards is the DHCP range. The pi sits on 42 because I need to connect to it from outside using port forwarding, so I give it a static IP

Comment: So this may not be the problem, but it can lead to problems. Does your DHCP server have option to statically assign IP addresses. Static-dhcp gives the advantage of static, but better manageability (the DHCP server has to be statically assigned).

Comment: Yes. As I said, the outer is configured to provide 192.168.0.1 - 127 as static IP range and 128 and up are DHCP.